# Solving $\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt} + \mathbf{G}(t) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{z}(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Is there a known solution for the linear equation below?
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt} + \mathbf{G}(t) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{z}(t)
$$
The variables $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of $n$ elements, $\mathbf{z}$ is the external driver term which is also a vector of $n$ elements, and $\mathbf{G}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix that is a function of time $t$.

**What I know so far**

Assuming $\mathbf{G}(t)$ is diagonalizable, we can decompose $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{P}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{-1}$ with diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$.
If the eigenvector matrix $\mathbf{P}$ can be made constant over time, by defining $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{z}$, we obtain separable linear equations

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt} + \boldsymbol{\Lambda}(t) \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{w}(t)
$$

which can be solved using Green's function.

However, if the eigenvector matrix $\mathbf{P}$ can't be made constant, then I'm stuck at the equation below
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{dt} + \left(\mathbf{P}^{-1}\frac{d\mathbf{P}}{dt}(t) + \boldsymbol{\Lambda}\right) \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{w}(t)
$$
which, unfortunately, the term besides $\mathbf{u}$ might not be separable (due to the $\frac{d\mathbf{P}}{dt}(t)$ term). I can repeat the exercise by decomposing the matrix besides $\mathbf{u}$, but it seems like there's no guarantee that it will arrive to separable equations.

Is there any way to solve the linear equation above?

Comment: In the homogeneous case, there is the [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion). There's probably a way to extend that to the inhomogenous case.

Comment: Also that derivative term should be $\mathbf{P}^{-1}d\mathbf{P}/dt$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks for the direction and the correction!

Comment: In the case where $G$ commutes with $\int G$, we have that $\exp \int G$ is a fundamental matrix of solutions for the homogeneous equation; the particular solution can be constructed from this via variation of parameters.